# Update winforms Paint.Add every second

Tags: winforms, f#

I am trying to make a small application with a seconds counter that rotates clockwise every second in a circle. I have figured out many of the parts, but cannot get the line to update every second as I wish. I have below pasted a MWE, that simply rotates the hand 90 degrees. I would like it to rotate 360/60*s (where s is the current second) degrees every second.

I have tried a number of things with the timer object (see lines at the bottom), but none have helped. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Drawing

// Prepare window form
let win = new System.Windows.Forms.Form ()
// Set some properties
win.BackColor <- System.Drawing.Color.White
let height = 250
let width = 200
win.Size <- System.Drawing.Size (width, height)

// make a timer 
let timer = new Timer ()
timer.Interval <- 1000 // create an event every 1000 millisecond 
timer.Enabled <- true // activate the timer

let getEndPoint degrees =
  let t = float 50
  let s = float 0
  let theta = float degrees * (System.Math.PI / float 180)
  let u = (s * (cos theta) + t * (sin theta)) + float 100
  let v = (-s * (sin theta) + -t * (cos theta)) + float 100
  Point (int u,int v)

// Set paint call-back function
let paint (e : PaintEventArgs) (x) : unit = 
    let pen = new Pen (Color.Black)
    let endPoint = getEndPoint x
    let points = [|Point (100,100); endPoint|] 
    e.Graphics.DrawLines (pen, points)

let getDegrees =
  360/60*System.DateTime.Now.Second

let addPaint degrees =
  printfn "Draws with degrees %A" degrees
  win.Paint.Add (fun e -> (paint e degrees))

win.Paint.Add (fun e -> (paint e 90))
//timer.Tick.Add (fun e -> (addPaint 90)) // Doesn't draw
//timer.Tick.Add (fun e -> (addPaint getDegrees)) // Doesn't draw, updates every second, but doesn't change degrees 
//timer.Tick.Add (fun e -> (addPaint (360/60*System.DateTime.Now.Second))) // Doesn't draw, but get correct degrees 

// Start the event-loop.
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run win
```

Comment: hint: getDegrees are not a function in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue by using the following two lines:

```
win.Paint.Add (fun e -> (paint e (360/60*System.DateTime.Now.Second)))
timer.Tick.Add (fun e -> win.Invalidate())
```